# AddSigningCredentials is working with Expired certiticate

Tags: identityserver4, pfx, code-signing-certificate, duende-identity-server

As per my implementation, we are creating the certificate in the pfx file and using that in the startup "AddSigningCredentials" method. Before assigning the certificate to this method we are checking the whether the certificate has expired or not. If that is not expired we are continuing with that and incase if that is expired we are creating a new certificate and using it.

Here my Question is as we are doing this process in the startup which will get executed only once at the time of Application start and the Functionality is working fine even with the expired certificate. When we restart the application then we are start getting the issue in "AddSigningCredentials" method.

Is this the expected behaviour or do we need to check the expiry of the certiricate for every request and call method "AddSigningCredentials". Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the certificate expiration.

IdentityServer just cares about the private key found inside the certificate, not the domain or expire-time of the certificate. The certificate file is just a container that hold the private key for you.

Comment: Hi @Tore Nestenius, Thanks for Responding. Could you please help me to understanding this further.  How long can i use the same certificate with same private for my Identity Server. Do i need to regenerate the private key at any point of time?

Comment: You can keep the same key forevever, as the key it self has no expire time, but in many deployments, rotating(replacing) the keys regularly can be benefitial.  There is also a built in module for automatically managing the keys at https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/keys/automatic_key_management/

Comment: As we are not using the Business edition of identity server and we can't use the duende automatic key management. Could you please tell me In which cases rotating the key is beneficial.

Comment: its if the key would be stolen, then the hacker could issue their own valid tokens, so because of that replacing the keys on a regular basis can be a solution. But it all depends on the risks. some never do change their keys.